# SqlCommand placeholder parameters: "Incorrect syntax near '?'" and "Must declare the scalar variable @param"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am developing a web mapping application intranet for our company. I am creating an "add polygon" function on the map. I use AspMap, VB.NET and SQL Server. When a user clicks a button to add a new record from the web form input data attribute, the error ***Incorrect syntax near '?'*** occurs.

My code is:

```
Private Sub AddNewShape(ByVal checklist_id As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal shape As AspMap.Shape, ByVal address_area As String, ByVal dmz As String, ByVal customerid As String, ByVal source As String, ByVal area As String, ByVal instalatur As String, ByVal developer As String, ByVal data_received As DateTime, ByVal doc_data As DateTime, ByVal datereport As DateTime, ByVal remark As String)
    Dim tableName As String

    Select Case shape.ShapeType
        Case AspMap.ShapeType.Line
            tableName = "lines"
        Case AspMap.ShapeType.Polygon
            tableName = "sambungan_baru"
        Case Else
            Return
    End Select

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = GetDbConnection()
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & " (CHECKLIST_ID, TYPE, SHAPEDATA, ADDRESS_AREA, DMZ, CUSTOMERID, SOURCE, AREA, INSTALATUR, DEVELOPER, DATA_RECEIVED, DOC_DATA, DATA_SENT, REMARK) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CHECKLIST_ID", checklist_id)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TYPE", type)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SHAPEDATA", shape.ShapeData)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ADDRESS_AREA", address_area)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DMZ", dmz)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CUSTOMERID", customerid)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SOURCE", source)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AREA", area)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("INSTALATUR", instalatur)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DEVELOPER", developer)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATA_RECEIVED", data_received)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOC_DATA", doc_data)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATA_SENT", datereport)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("REMARK", remark)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

    ReloadShapesDatabase()
End Sub
```

I changed this:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & " (CHECKLIST_ID, TYPE, SHAPEDATA, ADDRESS_AREA, DMZ, CUSTOMERID, SOURCE, AREA, INSTALATUR, DEVELOPER, DATA_RECEIVED, DOC_DATA, DATA_SENT, REMARK) VALUES *(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

to this:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & " (CHECKLIST_ID, TYPE, SHAPEDATA, ADDRESS_AREA, MZ, CUSTOMERID, SOURCE, AREA, INSTALATUR, DEVELOPER, DATA_RECEIVED, DOC_DATA, DATA_SENT, REMARK)(@checklist_id, @type, @shapedata, @address_area, @dmz, @conection, @source, @area, @instalatur, @developer, @data_received, @doc_data, data_sent, @remark)"
```

And I run into the alert: **Must declare the scalar variable "@conection".** Can anyone help me?

Comment: Was missing out the keyword "VALUES" in your revised insert statement just a typo?

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing two different styles of parameters in SQL queries. The ODBC syntax uses simple placeholder '?' character for each parameter, and the parameters are replaced in the same order that you add them to the parameters collection. For an `OdbcCommand`, the name you give the parameters is ignored, and only their sequence matters.

For a `SqlCommand`, the parameter names are meaningful; when the command executes, it will be run through a SQL Stored procedure that takes a list of parameter names and values and substitutes them into the T-SQL query. In this case, the order you add parameters to your query isn't important, but you need to make sure the names are correct (including the "@" prefix.)

The proper way to use a `SqlCommand` with parameters is as follows:

```
// The SQL Query: Note the use of named parameters of the form
// @ParameterName1, @ParameterName2, etc.
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & _
"    (CHECKLIST_ID, TYPE, SHAPEDATA ) " & _
"VALUES " & _
"    (@ChecklistId, @Type, @ShapeData )"

// The Parameter List. Note that the Parameter name must exactly match
// what you use in the query:
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckListId", checklist_id)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShapeData", shape.ShapeData)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for suggest. I've change '?,?..' to '@' prefix and error now is: "A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
System.FormatException:
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeoData.Read(BinaryReader r)
  at SqlGeometry::.DeserializeValidate(IntPtr , Int32 , CClrLobContext* )
.
The statement has been terminated." What the mean is alert that?

Comment: The error is saying that one of the resulting columns has data that is invalid; from the error it appears that you are trying to read a GEOGRAPHY data type column out of SQL but the value contained there doesn't appear to be valid geographic data.

Comment: I've try to change datatype from geometry to geograpghy but still is not working. I am using AspMap as Mapping Engine, so maybe the result from digitizing on webform not compatible data type with geometry/geography in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign parameters like this and in your case you missed providing value for "CONECTION" parameter. Also as an additional note, you should always enclose connection objects in using blocks. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) and look at the "Remarks" section.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES _
                     (@Col1Val, @Col2Val, @Col3Val)"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1Val","1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2Val","2");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3Val","3");
```

Comment: Hi Ashish.. thanks a lot for your suggest. I've changed odbcCommand to sqlcommand. But it'is still any trouble like above.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)` uses `conn` with an open connection.

Then verify your parameters type to be in accordance with the database table definition. Plus, If your using string type you may add an ' before and after any text inserted.

To be sure, you can break on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and copy the value of the command associated and running it to any SQL manager tool.

Finally, dispose your `cmd`.

Otherwise check if this is helpful for your issue : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/9d75106a-b0d4-49cc-ac86-d41cba4ab797